# How do i fix this python reverse range palindrome?

Tags: python, palindrome

This is for an assignment. We have to translate some provided java code into Python. Most of it was simple however the last bit is messing with my head. The whole code is a menu with one of the options being 'To display Palindromes up to 1000'. They're wanting a translation rather than a re-write - I'm sure there is a million ways to do it. What am I getting wrong in the method part ...

```
    def isPalindrome(n):
        str_n = str(n)
        reverse = ""
        for i in range(len(str_n)-1, -1, -1):
            reverse = reverse + str_n[i]
            result = str_n == reverse
            return result
```

there is some other menu code here ......

```
    elif option == 3:
        print("PALINDROMES")
        for i in range(0, 1000):
            if isPalindrome(i):
                print(i)
            break
```

Comment: You probably have typo and `break` should be in `if isPalindrome(i):` body rather than outside (should be one more level of indentation, so it is aligned with `print(i)`)

Comment: (1) `result = str_n == str_n[::-1]` — no need for a `for`-cycle, (2) `break` is indented incorrectly, (3) `result = ...` and subsequent `return` is indented incorrectly.

Comment: Check your indentation

Comment: They have specifically asked for the for cycle .... for i in range(len(str_n)-1,???,???):
                          reverse = reverse + str_n[i]

Comment: and return ????

Answer (score 2):

As far as I understand your question you want to check if the numbers is palindromes? Such as `11` is but `13` is not?

Anyway the easiest way is to use `[::-1]`, which will reverse a list or string, so you can code like:

```
def is_palindrome(text):
    if text == text[::-1]:
        print(f"({text} is a palindrome!)")
```

Comment: It needs to print all the palindromes in the (1, 1000) range. It also has to use this basic format ... I just think I have something wrong with in it ....

Answer (score 0):

You just have to find a way to reverse the given string, if its number you need to convert it into string then do it.
here is one of the way to reverse string

```
a="Hello"
s=""
for i in a:
    s=i+s
print(s)
```

using the above reversing method in your case it will be

```
def isPalindrome(n):
    str_n = str(n)
    reverse = ""
    for i in str_n:
        reverse = i + reverse
    if(reverse==str_n):
        #palindrome
        return True
    else:
        #not palindrome
        return False
print(isPalindrome(111))
```

Output:
`True`

Answer (score 0):

All sorted now .. thanks guys .... I ended up with this - it works and follows our assignment task :D

```
    def isPalindrome(n):
        str_n = str(n)
        reverse = ""
        for i in range(len(str_n)-1, -1, -1):
            reverse = reverse + str_n[i]
        if(reverse == str_n):
            return True

    print("PALINDROMES")
    for i in range(0, 1000):
        if isPalindrome(i):
           print(i)
```